# Simulate a camera node on ros kinetic

Tags: camera, ros

Ros noob here.

I'm trying to create a fake camera node for ros kinetic, in order to test the downstream subscribers that will process the images.

Problem is I have no idea where to start, does this kind of module exist?

I already have the test images that I'll drop into a folder, the camera node have to pick those images and publish them on a topic.

The ultimate goal is test automation in an environment that has no camera USB/IP plugged in. The majority of the tutorials I found focus on real camera input processing, which is not my purpose here.

Comment: You can write a ROS node which reads images from your folder and publish them on a topic. Basically, read images using opencv (maybe), then convert to required format (using cvbridge if on C++), then publish on a topic with type Image. Something like [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/99831/publish-file-to-image-topic/?answer=129176#post-id-129176) in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cameras in ROS are defined by the [image transport](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport), which means not just publishing some images. To fulfill all requirements which allows usage of image transport features you should make use of the [image publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/image_publisher) which deals with publishing the *image_raw* and *camera_info* topics.

You can find a very good [image transport sample code](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/PublishingImages#CA-95c080aca4f42c59f694f2236882a4027df983fe_1), which already shows almost a possible solution for your problem. The code loads an image of your device using OpenCV and publishes it as camera. By replacing the image file parameter `argv[3]` with a directory and some slight modifications, you should be able to load and publish several different images of a directory and publish not only one image.

Comment: Thanks, this image transport sample code and the global approach @akshayk07 told about helped me to build my super simple sensor_msgs/Image publisher and subscriber (I wrote it in python).
I didn't think I'd require the cvbridge features but it was easier for me to use it when reading a bunch of multiple size jpg files in my input folder.